# Where better to whet one's grammar?

Tags: grammar, pronouns, questions, rhetorical-devices

I wonder if all interrogative pronouns can be used in structures like

> Where better to learn about the resilience of life?

For example,

> Who better to repair my car?
>
> How better to cook potatoes than by baking?

Comment: In modern grammar, "where" is a not a pronoun but a preposition.

Comment: It is not clear what motivates this question. Why do you doubt that these words could be used that way?

Comment: My first thought was that it wouldn't be easy to come up with a context where ***Why** better to...?* would sound natural. But I can't really argue with [*Then, why, oh! why is it better to teach boys Greek and Latin than to teach them the best principles of prosperity? **Why better to** develop literary taste than business tact and financial acumen.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22why+better+to+develop%22) It's not *quite* the same construction as OP's examples, though.

Comment: But how about other comparatives? _Better_ is definitely  the prototype, but *_How faster to cook the meat?_, *_What handier than a pocket knife?_, *_Who more interested than he?_ suggest that there's an idiomatic structure requiring _better_.

Comment: @JohnLawler Does this construction require a form of *WHIZ* deletion? Grammatically, although it is a subordinate clause, at least in form, it still seems to be missing a subject and a tensed from of the  verb *be*. The missing subject itself looks like it should be a dummy subject, and the infinitival clause at the end looks like it should be an extra posed subject: "*Where **is it** better [**to learn about the resilience of life**]?*" Or something like that.

Comment: *Where*, *what*, and *how* are not interrogative pronouns.

Comment: @TinfoilHat Calling *what* a pronoun is certainly fair game.

Comment: @JohnLawler But of course, if it does use a (non-relative clause) form of WHIZ deletion, then the original clause would no longer have the structure of a subordinate clause, I suppose, but a regular question.

Comment: Damn. I've been working on _Tell me when (it) would be a good time to leave_ (note optional extrapositionality) and hoped to have something to post soon. This is just another idiom involving infinitives and _wh_-words. Details when I get a better look.

Comment: @Araucaria-Him — See, maybe, 8.1.4 Verbless exclamatives in *CGEL*.

Comment: @Araucaria-Him I'm really not interested in CGEL's terminology. It's all name magic; I'm much more interested in syntactic derivations, which they  essentially ignore.

Comment: @Araucaria-Him Yes, sorry. Too many names.

Comment: @JohnLawler Sorry, shouldn't have said *WHIZ* but rather subject + *be* deletion, albeit in a *wh*-environment.

Comment: Title should be "Where better to whet one's grammar?"

Comment: @StuartF HippoSawrUs Yes, mea culpa.

Comment: @TinfoilHat English exclamative only use *how* and *what*, though.

Answer (score 5):

**Short answer (tl;dr):**

You can use open interrogative words like *who*, but not closed ones like *whether*.

Some open interrogative words appear only very rarely in this construction.

---

**Full answer:**

We often distinguish open questions and closed questions. Modern English uses the interrogative words *whether* and *if* for closed questions (for example *yes/no* questions) and a larger set of interrogative *wh*-words such as *who, what* and so-forth for open questions. We sometimes call the latter *open interrogative words*.

The words *if* and *whether* can only occur at the beginning of subordinate clauses, but the others can occur in main clauses too:

1. Will Bob be there?
2. *Whether Bob will be there? - [*whether* with main clause, ungrammatical]
3. *If Bob will be there? - [*if* with main clause, ungrammatical]
4. I wonder whether Bob will be there.
5. I wonder if Bob will be there.

Compare those with:

6. Who will be there? [*who* with main clause]
7. I wonder who will be there? [*who* with subordinate clause]

The Original Poster's construction can use  open interrogative words, but not the closed interrogative words *whether* or *if*:

8. *If better to eat cake than with chocolate on. (ungrammatical)
9. *Whether better to be on holiday than this. (ungrammatical)

The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language (Huddleston & Pullum, 2002) recognise eight common open interrogative *wh*-words in modern English:

- *how, what, when, where, which, who, whose, why*

There's also the word *whom* which is an accusative form of the word *who*, of course.

All of these open interrogative words,I believe, can be used in the OP's *better to* construction. Here are some examples from *COCA*, [The Corpus of Contemporary American English](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/):

10. *How better to commemorate your engagement than including your beloved pets in your session?*
11. *What better to attach to your lace-trimmed veil than Mickey Mouse ears?*
12. *When better to take on the enemy?*
13. *Where better to start than the city that doesn't sleep -- New York City!*
14. *Who better to motivate you than your other half?*

So for *how, what, when, where* and *who*, there's no argument and the data clearly prove that these interrogative words appear in this *better to* construction. However, neither COCA nor the larger *iWEB* or *NOW* corpuses were able to come up with examples using the interrogative words *whose, which* or *why*. Problematically, the searches themselves were not always successful; instead of showing '*no results*' the searches led to a results page where no hits were actually listed. Not sure what exactly is going on there. Although I didn't try too hard, I was also unable to pull any such examples off the web. Nonetheless, I am confident that the following made-to-order examples are passable:

15. *And whose spin doctor better to throw under the bus than your very own?*
16. *And which chocolate better to hand over to this bully than the one she'd just fished out of her dogs mouth?*
17. *Why better to turn over a new leaf than because of the birth of your first child?*

If you can come up with better ones, or can find any attested examples, do let me know in the comments.

Why is it so difficult to find such examples on the internet? There might be many pragmatic reasons. For example, consider (15) above. Exactly the same effect can be achieved with much less grammatical complexity  by using a simple *who* as the initial interrogative phrase and introducing the genitive in the comparative phrase:

18. *And who better to throw under the bus than your very own spin doctor?*

Similar arguments can be made for the cases of *which* and *why*. So, in short, closed interrogative words are barred from from this construction but open interrogative ones seem to be fine, although it's certainly the case that some of them  only occur very rarely.

Comment: _Whether better to be, or not to be?_

Comment: @JohnLawler I wondered about that. I've left the semantics and structure proper for you, but the following thoughts seemed to work against it. First the OP's examples seem to work well as stand alone rhetorical questions, the *whether* one not so much. Pragmatically, the OP's rhetorical questions could be paraphrased as *There's no place better to learn about the resilience of life* and *There's no-one better to repair my car*. I can't seem to get that with the *weather* question. In the OP's construction there's a comparative phrase, which is missing in the *to be* one.

Comment: @JohnLawler  It also seems to lack some of the idiomaticity of the OP's. For example, maybe it works just as well with  a different adjective: *whether faster to go by rail or air*, for example. What do you think?

Comment: I think you're right. _Whether_ can only work embedding a y/n question, and that doesn't have the same facility as other _wh_-words.

Answer (score 1):

**Who better to** and **how better to** are both perfectly acceptable - see [this](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=who+better+to%2Cwhere+better+to%2Chow+better+to&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3). You could also say

> What better way of cooking potatoes than baking?

Comment: "Where better to put the dressing than on the wound?" or maybe "on the salad" but using *Where* like that is fine too.

Comment: @AndrewLeach - I didn't mention _where_ because the OP implied that they knew that to be acceptable.

Comment: I don't disagree that these occur (see my answer). However, the Ngrams aren't very helpful because, for example in the case of *how*, they are mostly instances of sentences such as: *The duke probably intended to pay the author a compliment, but did not now how better to do it than in this blunt and apparently rude way*. Although the wording in the subordinate clause there is similar to OP's, the meaning is different. OP's examples work as stand alone sentences, which is an important aspect of their grammar.